# Python 3.4 help - using slicing to replace characters in a string

Tags: python-3.4

Say I have a string.

`"poop"`

I want to change `"poop"` to `"peep"`.

In fact, I also want all of the o's in poop to change to e's for any word I put in.

Here's my attempt to do the above.

```
def getword():
    x = (input("Please enter a word."))
    return x
def main():
    y = getword()
    for i in range (len(y)):
        if y[i] == "o":
            y = y[:i] + "e"
    print (y)

main()
```

As you can see, when you run it, it doesn't amount to what I want. Here is my expected output.

```
Enter a word. 
>>> brother
brether
```

Something like this. I **need** to do it using slicing. I just don't know how.

Please keep your answer simple, since I'm somewhat new to Python. Thanks!

Comment: You can use y.replace("o", "e") and avoid loops and slicing altogether.

Comment: I did that, and it didn't work. PLus this is homework and slicing is required. @MirekE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses slicing (but keep in mind that slicing is not the best way to do it):

```py
def f(s):
    for x in range(len(s)):
        if s[x] == 'o':
            s = s[:x]+'e'+s[x+1:]
    return s
```

Comment: would this be the complete code? or should I put this under `def getWord()` and change f to main? @Ourous

Comment: @asdfmovie Just replace the body of the `main` method with lines 2-4, and add `s=getword()` on top and `print(s)` on the bottom. :)

Answer (score 1):

Strings in python are non-mutable, which means that you can't just swap out letters in a string, you would need to create a whole new string and concatenate letters on one-by-one

```
def getword():
    x = (input("Please enter a word."))
    return x

def main():
    y = getword()
    output = ''
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if y[i] == "o":
            output = output + 'e'
        else:
            output = output + y[i]
    print(output)

main()
```

I'll help you this once, but you should know that stack overflow is not a homework help site. You should be figuring these things out on your own to get the full educational experience.

**EDIT**

Using slicing, I suppose you could do:

```
def getword():
        x = (input("Please enter a word."))
        return x

def main():
    y = getword()
    output = ''                                       # String variable to hold the output string. Starts empty
    slice_start = 0                                   # Keeps track of what we have already added to the output. Starts at 0
    for i in range(len(y) - 1):                       # Scan through all but the last character
        if y[i] == "o":                               # If character is 'o'
            output = output + y[slice_start:i] + 'e'  # then add all the previous characters to the output string, and an e character to replace the o
            slice_start = i + 1                       # Increment the index to start the slice at to be the letter immediately after the 'o'
    output = output + y[slice_start:-1]               # Add the rest of the characters to output string from the last occurrence of an 'o' to the end of the string
    if y[-1] == 'o':                                  # We still haven't checked the last character, so check if its an 'o'
        output = output + 'e'                         # If it is, add an 'e' instead to output
    else:
        output = output + y[-1]                       # Otherwise just add the character as-is
    print(output)

main()
```

Comments should explain what is going on. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient or best way to do it (which really shouldn't matter, since slicing is a terribly inefficient way to do this anyways), just the first thing I hacked together that uses slicing.

EDIT Yeah... Ourous's solution is much more elegant

Comment: I see. Can you use slicing? It's required in the assignment. I can learn from this however.

Comment: I think when you use slicing you can use it with lists. like slicing parts of lists. @rfj001

Answer (score 0):

Can slicing even be used in this situation??

The only probable solution I think would work, as MirekE stated, is `y.replace("o","e")`.

Comment: I don't know. @Player72